# MatLab fmincon constrained optimization "Not enough input arguments."

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I did this

```
function f=objfun(w)
a=0.5
w0=[0.1;0.2;0.3];
f=(a^2)/2 + w(1)+ w(2)+ w(3);

[w,fval]=fmincon('objfun',w0,[],[],[],[],[],[],'constraint')
```

But I got this error message.

```
Error using objfun (line 3)
Not enough input arguments.
```

What problem is it talking about?

I learned `fmincon` from

```
http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/classes/331/lab/fmincon.html
```

and it tells me that codes like this

```
function f=objfun(x)

f=x(1)^4-x(1)^2+x(2)^2-2*x(1)+x(2);
```

will be the first lines to do constrained optimization.

What has gone wrong?

Comment: Your code is mixed up, e.g. you define `w0` within objfun. Moreover, `fmincon` requires at least four input arguments: `(fun,x0,A,b)`. Maybe you should first learn about the function from the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html

Comment: Some of first things you learn as a Matlab user: when using  or learning about a new function, type `help nameoffunction` in the Matlab command window and read. Then (or instead) you can either click the link at the bottom of the help or you can type `doc nameoffunction` to read more in depth in a nice browser window. Googling the name of a function should only be done after you've exhausted these resources and while realizing that what you find might not even apply to your version of Matlab.

Comment: @A.Donda Initially I wrote a simplified version of my code to stackoverflow. But in my code fmincon is like [x,fval]=fmincon('objfun',w0,[],[],[],[],[],[],'constraint')   so the insufficiency of input arguments may not be the problem.

Comment: Ok, so do I understand correctly that you call `fmincon` within your objective function? Seriously, please read the documentation first.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to pass a function handle to fmincon. From the docs http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html

```
x = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b)
```

where myfun is a MATLAB® function such as

```
function f = myfun(x)
f = ...            % Compute function value at x
```

Try passing a function handle to fmincon. I assume that constraints is your non linear constraint function, it should be a function handle as well. I also assume that you are not calling fmincon from inside your objective function. If so then I think you will have some thing like this:

objfun.m

```
 function f = objfun(w)
    a=0.5;
    f=(a^2)/2 + w(1)+ w(2)+ w(3);
    return
end
```

main.m

```
 w0=[0.1;0.2;0.3];
[w,fval]=fmincon(@objfun,w0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@constraint)
```